# Include Directory in Bundle.config

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

Is it possible to include a whole directory rather than just a path in `Bundle.config`? Its much easier than explicitly stating each file.

I've typed in `directory` as an attribute for the `include` tag but auto-suggest isn't suggesting anything which makes me think its not possible?

For example;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
    <include path="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />
    <include directory="~/Content/SomeDirectory" />
  </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364077/bundles-config-can-it-include-scripts), there's an XSD that determines what can go in the `Bundle.config` file.

The `include` element is defined as such:

```
<xs:complexType name="include">
  <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

So the only allowed format is `<include path="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />`, where `path` is expected to point at a single file ([see `ReadBundle()` in `BundleManifest.cs`](https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Optimization/BundleManifest.cs)).