# Can the Bundle.config include ScriptBundles?

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

Can I include scripts in my `Bundle.config` file, or is it only for style bundles?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bundles version="1.0">
  <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
    ...
  </styleBundle>
  <scriptBundle path="~/Scripts">

    Is this possible?

  </scriptBundle>
</bundles>
```

Also can anyone provide a link to a `Bundle.config` reference that explains the possible tags and structure? I've searched but all I can come up with is the `BundleConfig.cs` code way of bundling rather than the markup. I realise why - the markup way is older and maybe even deprecated. But I would like to learn the markup way as its common I will be working with legacy systems that use the older method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a "bundle manifest". This is an XML file located at `~/bundle.config` and loaded through `BundleManifest.ReadBundleManifest();` in your `Application_Start`.

There is an [XSD in CodePlex, named BundleManifestSchema.xsd](https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Optimization/BundleManifestSchema.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="BundleConfig" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="include">
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="styleBundle">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="include" type="include" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="cdnPath" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="scriptBundle">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="include" type="include" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="path" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="cdnPath" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="cdnFallbackExpression" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="bundles">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element type="styleBundle" name="styleBundle" />
        <xs:element type="scriptBundle" name="scriptBundle" />
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

So yes, `scriptBundle` is supported.

Answer (score 2):

I [don't think it's possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/14/adding-bundling-and-minification-to-web-forms.aspx) and I think you should really avoid using the XML notation. There are almost no resources regarding that topic on the web. So it might be faster to just rewrite the XML to C#. However, there is a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcBundleConfig/) package that will allow you to configure it via XML. The example can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tdupont750/MvcBundleConfig/blob/master/MvcApplication/Bundles.config) and on the [project site](http://www.tomdupont.net/2012/03/configuring-bundles-in-mvc-4.html).